# Grails and Java: Proper way to unmarshall Json from Grails in Java app

Tags: java, rest, grails, unmarshalling

I'm quite new to Grails things. here the problem:

I created a simple class exposed as a REST service with grail. (I only use grail for CRUD operation on database).

I have an Java FX application that needs to consume this service to recreate the original object. Is there a clean way to "export" domain class from grails ?

Thx in advance for any help !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create common java library for both projects, include in Grails app and JavaFX app. This common library will share common classes. For marshalling/demarshalling JSON you can use [Jackson](http://java.dzone.com/tips/json-processing-using-jackson)

Answer (score 0):

[GSON](https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) or [Jackson](http://jackson.codehaus.org/) will do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/webServices.html#domainResources.

For example, if you are returning a "book" domain class from your REST service you could use:

```
render book as JSON
```